# PHP: удаление куки срабатывает только после обновления страницы!

Tags: php, авторизация

Приветствую всех! Пожалуйста, помогите найти решение. Проблема такая: есть страница авторизации, если юзер правильно ввел логин и пароль, то его перекидывает на его личную страничку. 
файл - `auth_page.php`: страница с формой для авторизации, отсюда все данные методом пост передаются на следующий файл проверки;
файл - `auth_process`: файл получает все данные от `auth_page.php` и проверяет на наличие ошибок, и если ошибок нет, то редирект идет на страницу пользователя;

Для того что бы авторизованная сессия "жила" по больше времени, была использована функция - `setcookie("id", "[ значение ]", time()+3600*24*30, "/", "домен");`

Когда пользователь уже на сайте, для завершения своей сессии ему нужно нажать на соответствующую кнопку выхода - эта кнопка реализована в форме:

```
<form method="post" action="quit.php">
<input type="submit" name="logout" value="выход">
</form>
```

В файле `quit.php` имеется скрипт для уничтожения cookie.
`setcookie("id", "[ значение ]", time()-3600*24*30, "/", "домен");`
После этого идет редирект обратно на страницу авторизации `auth_page.php`.

**Проблема:** даже после всех этих манипуляций, при нажатии на браузерную кнопку "назад", все страницы, которые ранее были открыты - будут доступны для обозрения, невзирая на то, что в каждом фале есть скрипт проверяющий наличие куки, и только в том случае, если все нужные куки были обнаружены и если их значения совпали с записями из БД, то только после этого должна отображаться информация на странице.

**Вопрос:** как сделать так, чтобы после удаления куки все предыдущие страницы были не доступны?

Comment: 1. а зачем вы сессию сами то пишете, в php она уже реализована ? 
2. проще удалять данные авторизации из сессии (что нить вроде **`unset($_SESSION['user_id']);`** )

Comment: Функция session_start() и $_SESSION[], вы правы все было бы круто, вообще сайт изначально и был написан посредством $_SESSION. Завершения сессии на сайте происходило как надо, срабатывало session_destroy(). Но тут проблема другого рода. По умолчанию в php.ini время жизни сессии выставлена как 1440 секунд(24 минуты), после истечения этого времени сессия на сайте сбрасывается, и пользователь должен залогиниться вновь. Доступа к конфигам php.ini хостинга где лежит сам сайт - нет. А сессия пользователя должна висеть долго, срок - один месяц, устраивает. По этому решил переписать на куках

Comment: ну и все равно, можно было бы просто повторить механизм сессий "вручную", все то-же самое только не использовать встроенный механизм а делать что то типа $session=new Session(); там где надо. В куках же хранить  данные авторизации небезопасно как минимум.

Answer (score 6):

Не уверен на 100%, но попробуйте запретить кэширование:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: " . date("r"));
```

Comment: Ваш метод работает!!! Спасибо огромное! Вы мне очень помогли! Дали мне ответ, который мне не смог дать Google (ну или я плохо объяснил ему свою проблему). Всем спасибо огромное!

Comment: Это 100% кеш! Нужно на всех страницах приватного раздела запретить кеширование.